# Why does this shared_ptr code segfault? When do shared_ptr's free?

Tags: c++, scope, shared-ptr

I've made a SSCE as best I can. My suspicion is that the shared pointers deconstruct (free) my objects before I ask for them in main. How can I prevent this without circumventing shared pointers altogether? This is in isolated problem in a program that otherwise is greatly helped by the use of shared_ptrs.

Test.h:

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Test
{
    public:
        Test();
        virtual ~Test();
        static std::shared_ptr<Test> makeTestFrom(std::string l);
        std::vector<std::shared_ptr<int>> reg_vec;
    protected:
    private:

};

#endif // TEST_H
```

Test.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
Test::Test():
reg_vec()
{
    //ctor
}

Test::~Test()
{
    //dtor
}
std::shared_ptr<Test> Test::makeTestFrom(std::string l)
{
    std::shared_ptr<Test> sp(new Test());
    std::shared_ptr<int> i(new int(3));
    sp->reg_vec.push_back(i);
    return sp;
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "include/Test.h"
using namespace std;

 int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<Test> x(new Test());
    x->makeTestFrom("loldoesntmatter");
    std::cout << x->reg_vec[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<Test> x(new Test());
    x->makeTestFrom("loldoesntmatter"); // you discarded the return
    std::cout << x->reg_vec[0] << std::endl; // x->reg_vec is empty
    return 0;

}
```

Also, too many shared pointers

Comment: Oh good lord I discarded the return... it is very late, LOL. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 3):

You're making too many new objects.  In `main`, you're looking for an `int` inside `x->reg_vec`, but `makeTestFrom` doesn't add anything to `x`, it creates a brand-new object and puts the integer inside that.

Besides that, you're abusing `shared_ptr`.  In C++, avoid dynamic allocation when you can.  `int` are cheaper to pass by value than with `shared_ptr`, so just use `vector<int>`.  And `Test` objects can be created with automatic lifetime also.

Just because some other languages (i.e. Java) make everything a handle doesn't mean that's a good pattern for C++.

Comment: Java does not make a handle on primitive types like int, float, double, long, bool, etc, but passes these by value

Comment: @Johannes: We're talking about a collection, not individual primitives.  There is no equivalent to `vector<int>`, the Java generic collections do store elements by handle.  Besides that, the list of pass-by-value types in Java is closed, you can't define new ones.

Comment: Yes, that's true. My comment was just concerning your generic statement "other languages (i.e. Java) make everything a handle".